# Replace Custom String from Alt text in Image and Link

Tags: glass-mapper

In **AltText**

- Inserting string which contains HTML char {SomeString} breaks the page.(`Error: Input string is not correct format` - looks like alt text won't accept html characters)
- Consider if insert only string **SomeString** and wanted to replace alt text run time (in view) any option available in glass mapper?  i am using the below code to render the image and Link

  ```
  Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model, x => x.BackgroundImage)
  Html.Glass().BeginRenderLink(Model, x => x.Link)
  ```

Comment: The other question has valid answers for your question. Make sure that you apply them correctly instead of creating another post with same question.

Comment: Hi @MarekMusielak - Problem is that the solution not working in my solution. I know solution is correct. While i ask other ways (Galss mapper ways-Users asked me to create new question to maintain the purpose of community).
Could you please let me know what is the way to create this question (Any title name suggestion or anything so not consider as duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you want to set a static `alt` value in `RenderImage` method like.

```
@RenderImage(Model, x => x.BackgroundImage, new { @class = "anyclass", @alt = "SomeString" }, true)
```

If you want it to be dynamically populated from Sitecore based on configured image property you need to set the `Alternate Text` value in the image field level and use the below code.

```
@RenderImage(Model, x => x.BackgroundImage, new { @alt = Model.BackgroundImage.Alt }, true)
```

[image]

If you want the Image wrapped under the link try something like this.

```
@using (BeginRenderLink(Model, t => t.Link, new { @class = "anyclass" }, true))
{
  @RenderImage(Model, t => t.BackgroundImage, new { @alt = Model.BackgroundImage.Alt }, true)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try resolving it on runtime by creating an extension method for `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image` which returns you the updated `Alt` text after removing the HTML tags using `regex`.

So your method will look like this.

```
public static Image ValidateAlt(this Image image)
{
    image.Alt = Regex.Replace(image.Alt, "<.*?>", String.Empty);

    return image;
}
```

And use this in your view like below.

```
Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model, x => x.BackgroundImage.ValidateAlt())
```

Hope this will solve your issue.